# Can I point a Hostgator account to a Wix website?

Tags: web-hosting

One person has a website made on Wix, but he wants the email and other services of Hostgator. Is there any form that I can point a domain to hostgator (for getting the email, ftp services, etc.) and redirecting only the requests for the website to the wix account, keeping the link of the domain for displaying in the browser (and not making an unmasked redirect where they will see the wix link) and that everything works properly?

Comment: Mail uses separate DNS records so it is easy to configure that one independently.  Can you explain more about the FTP?  Is it a separate FTP subdomain?  What is the purpose.  Often FTP it's for uploading files to your site but if you are using Wix that wouldn't be needed.